# Rails : new asset path for PDF's not being recognised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, assets

I have a rails app in which I have added a new asset. I have added a new folder named `information`, in the assets folder, in which there is a PDF called `xyz.pdf`.

The problem is that I am trying to make a link to that PDF, however the application throws up an error: `No route matches [GET] "/assets/information/xyz.pdf"`

I have added the new asset in the `config/application.rb` file :

> config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/information"

This is the link I am using :

> ```
> <%= link_to "Information Pack", "assets/information/xyz.pdf", :class => "links" %>
> ```

Answer (score 10):

When using the asset pipeline, you should refer to any asset in the application with:

```
<%= link_to "Information Pack", asset_path("information/xyz.pdf"), :class => "links" %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "Information Pack", asset_path("xyz.pdf"), :class => "links" %>
```

This would generate a different path depending the running environment and the asset version number.

Comment: The problem is that the new asset folder is not being recognised for some reason, when I put the file in the `images` folder it works just fine.